# Uso de type="password" altera layout

Tags: html, css, password

Quando coloco  `type="password"` para não exibir a senha o *layout* da caixa de texto se altera. O que fazer?

Comment: Como assim "Se altera"?

Comment: A caixa de texto para digitar a senha não fica do mesmo tamanho do login(usuário). Além disso ela perde as cores e o fundo

Comment: não é porque seu estilo css esta configurado como type="text"?

Comment: coloca seu código para que sua pergunta seja compreendida melhor.

Comment: Estou começando agora nessa área. Na verdade eu estava apenas tentando entender com base no que se encontra disponível no site (bootsnipp) (https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dldxB). Eu estava mexendo por aí, mas percebi que quando coloco "password" para não mostrar a senha se altera o layout. O lInk se encontra a cima.

Comment: Obrigado aos senhores pela ajuda. Deu certo alterando o type=text do css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente é possível fazer uma alteração da caixa de texto mudando seu tipo. Como se trata de estilo, é provavel que em algum lugar no seu projeto possua um arquivo `.css` ou até mesmo dentro da tag `<style>` no qual pode haver uma simples mudança de estilo do seu input. Dê uma olhada abaixo como isso é possível:

```css
input[type="text"]{
    background: #eee;
    height: 40px;
    color: #000;
}

input[type="password"]{
    background: #ccc;
    height: 40px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
Login:
<br/>
<input type="text">
<br/>
Senha
<br/>
<input type="password">
<br/>
```

Dito isso, é necessário estilizar seu `input` com tipo *PASSWORD* para que mantenha mesma forma em outros tipo, como o tipo *TEXT*, ou algo similar.

Comment: Obrigado. Eu estava analisando o código e alterei o "type=text" do CSS assim como os colegas falaram. Muito obrigado pela resposta, foi de grande ajuda para meus estudos.

Answer (score 1):

O simples uso deste controle não altera estilo, mas como ele é um controle diferente de outros `input` pode ser que seu estilo não esteja configurado adequadamente para lidar com isto, a estilização pode não estar em cascata adequadamente e para este tipo esteja caindo em outro estilo. Para ter certeza só vendo o todo. Ou você faz a estilização para todos os controles (pelo menos nessa hierarquia da cascata) ou faz estilização para cada um. Me parece que o mais simples para o que deseja seria isto (o que não deve estar no seu código, por isso a falha):

```css
input {
    background: #C0C0C0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
Login:<br/>
<input type="text"><br/>
Senha:<br/>
<input type="password">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/AllInputsStyle.js).

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado pela resposta, foi de grande ajuda para meus estudos.

Comment: @ThiagoJhosé mudei porque acho que o que deseja é isto, a pergunta não mostrou o que estava fazendo então era complicado ter certeza. Ainda seria legal por algo para mostrar o problema, como fizemos aqui nas respostas.

Comment: E de fato a alteração do input já basta. O que o autor descreveu na pergunta não acontece normalmente, o problema dele é causado por um CSS anterior (ou seja, é um erro ou limitação no código dele, que não foi apresentado no post, e não um problema da tecnologia CSS em si). A resposta aceita na verdade é provavelmente só um um contorno

Answer (score -1):

Dúvida solucionada com a ajuda dos colegas. Obrigado a Todos.

Solução: Somente alterar o "type=text" para "type=password" do css.

Agradeço a Todos.